# meaning of "imagine being an atheist"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"One result of this scientific theory was that it became easier than ever before to believe that there is no God. The zoologist Richard Dawkins has written, ‘**I can’t imagine being an atheist at any time before 1859, when Darwin’s On the Origin of Species was published.**’ There were atheists, of course, before 1859 – David Hume, the subject of Chapter 17, was probably one – but there were many more afterwards. You don’t have to be an atheist to believe that evolution is true: many religious believers are Darwinists. But they can’t be Darwinists and believe that God created all species exactly as they are today."

What is exactly the meaning of the sentence "**I can’t imagine being an atheist at any time before 1859**"? I've tried to rewrite the sentence like this: 
"I can't imagine what it was like to be an atheist before 1859"
Is it correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Your understanding is correct. The author is implying that it was more difficult to be an atheist in the past than today, since the separation of church and state wasnt as common. "I cant imagine" is just an expression here.

Comment: @maxpleaner: That is one possible interpretation, and you might be right, but I don't think the question can be answered without more context.  The sentence could equally well mean "I can't imagine that I would have been an atheist (if I'd been around) at any time before 1859".  (Also, is the separation of church and state really that closely linked to the publication of On the Origin of Species in 1859?).

Comment: I think your alternate interpretation is probably right @rjpond

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to understand the phrase "I can't imagine being an atheist at any time before 1859".  It could mean:

- I can't imagine what it would have been like, being an atheist before 1859, *or*
- I can't imagine that I would have been an atheist before 1859, *i.e.* I highly doubt that I would have been an atheist (if I had been around) before 1859.

The context strongly points to the second interpretation: "it became easier than ever before to believe that there is no God... There were atheists, of course, before 1859... but there were many more afterwards."